py openc4 stich 2 webcam images to overlaping panoramic stream - not working
so im trying to take 2 webcam streams (wecams are fixed, spartially separated 200mm apart) there certain overlaping zone... i want to make pnaramic view and use overlaping zone for deistance detection but so far failing even to get panaramic stiching. tried all  type of code and  not even close resylsts even this looks like it should work
enter image description here
import cv2
import numpy as np

# Function to detect ORB keypoints and descriptors
def detect_and_compute(image):
    orb = cv2.ORB_create(nfeatures=10000)  # Maximize the number of keypoints
    keypoints, descriptors = orb.detectAndCompute(image, None)
    return keypoints, descriptors

# Function to match descriptors using Brute Force Matcher
def match_keypoints(des1, des2):
    bf = cv2.BFMatcher(cv2.NORM_HAMMING, crossCheck=True)
    matches = bf.match(des1, des2)
    matches = sorted(matches, key=lambda x: x.distance)  # Sort matches by distance
    return matches

# Function to stitch images together
def stitch_images(img1, img2, matches, kp1, kp2):
    # Extract location of good matches
    points1 = np.zeros((len(matches), 2), dtype=np.float32)
    points2 = np.zeros((len(matches), 2), dtype=np.float32)

    for i, match in enumerate(matches):
        points1[i, :] = kp1[match.queryIdx].pt
        points2[i, :] = kp2[match.trainIdx].pt

    # Compute homography
    H, mask = cv2.findHomography(points2, points1, cv2.RANSAC)

    # Warp img2 to img1's coordinate space
    height, width = img1.shape[:2]
    img2_warped = cv2.warpPerspective(img2, H, (width, height))

    # Combine the images (horizontal concatenation)
    stitched_img = np.hstack([img1, img2_warped])

    return stitched_img

# Capture two webcam streams
cap1 = cv2.VideoCapture(0)  # First webcam
cap2 = cv2.VideoCapture(1)  # Second webcam

while True:
    ret1, frame1 = cap1.read()
    ret2, frame2 = cap2.read()

    if not ret1 or not ret2:
        print("Failed to capture from webcams.")
        break

    # Detect and compute keypoints and descriptors
    kp1, des1 = detect_and_compute(frame1)
    kp2, des2 = detect_and_compute(frame2)

    # Match keypoints
    matches = match_keypoints(des1, des2)

    # Draw the matches for debugging (only a subset of the best matches)
    match_img = cv2.drawMatches(frame1, kp1, frame2, kp2, matches[:20], None, flags=cv2.DrawMatchesFlags_NOT_DRAW_SINGLE_POINTS)

    # Stitch images together
    stitched_img = stitch_images(frame1, frame2, matches, kp1, kp2)

    # Stack original frames (frame1 and frame2) vertically for debugging
    stacked_img = np.vstack([frame1, frame2])

    # Display original streams, the match visualization, and the stitched panoramic image
    cv2.imshow("Matches", match_img)
    cv2.imshow("Original Streams", stacked_img)
    cv2.imshow("Stitched Panoramic", stitched_img)

    # Exit loop on 'q' key press
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break

# Release the webcams and close all windows
cap1.release()
cap2.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()


